# Use SED to delete all lines between a single repeating pattern

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I'd like to use sed to delete all lines between a pattern that repeats throughout a text file.

#### Input

```
SET ENG_1
blah blah
blah blah
SET ENG_2
blah blah
blah blah
SET TEST
blah blah
blah blah
SET ENG_5
blah blah
blah blah
SET OPEN
blah blah
blah blah
SET ENG_10
blah blah
blah blah
```

There are multiple `SET ENG_#` lines, but I never know what the number on the end will be. I want to remove all lines between `SET ENG_` and the next line that starts with `SET`.

#### Desired output

```
SET ENG_1
SET ENG_2
SET TEST
blah blah
blah blah
SET ENG_5
SET OPEN
blah blah
blah blah
SET ENG_10
```

I would like to edit the file in place, like using the -i option in sed.

#### My attempt

Here is what I have tried:

```
sed -i "/SET ENG_/,/SET ENG_/{//!d}" $MYFILE
```

It only works on the first occurrence, so I get this output:

```
SET ENG_1
SET ENG_2
blah, blah
blah blah
```

How can I change my approach to obtain my desired output?

Comment: So, do you want to delete all lines between the **first** `set_eng` and the **last** `set_eng`? Is the number important?

Comment: How to determine **between** here. If `SET ENG_3` comes along then all the lines between `SET ENG_2` to `SET ENG_3` will also be deleted?

Comment: Glenn, yes. But it they are not always in order. Sometimes it could be SET ENG1,  SET TEST, SET OUT, SET ENG2.  The number is not important

Comment: @user3101337 I think you need to clarify what your expected output is by showing a better example with more then two `SET ...` lines and then the example of the final output.

Comment: Question has been updated with more information, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/SET/!b;:a;$!{N;ba};s/((SET)[^\n]*\n).*\n([^\n]*\2)/\1\3/' file
```

This will retain the first and last patterns (in your case `SET`).

This alternative will remove the first and last patterns as well:

```
sed -r '/SET/!b;:a;$!{N;ba};s/[^\n]*(SET).*\1[^\n]*\n?//' file
```

On reading the amendment to you question, perhaps this might work for you:

```
sed -ni ':a;/^SET ENG_[1-9]/{p;:b;$q;n;/^SET/ba;bb};p' file
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but see my updated question above, maybe this will help.

Comment: @user3101337 added  `-i` flag to edit in place and start of line anchors for regexp. Are you using GNU sed?

Answer (score 0):

If you have some text like this:

```
cat file
start text
SET ENG_1
blah blah
blah blah
SET ENG_2
blah blah
blah blah
SET ENG_3
blah blah
blah blah
SET ENG_4
end text
blah blah
blah blah
```

This will then print all data before first `SET ENG` and after last `SET ENG`:

```
awk '/SET ENG/ {e=NR;if (!f) f=NR} {a[NR]=$0} END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) if (f>i||i>e) print a[i]}' file
start text
end text
blah blah
blah blah
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk with custom record separator you can use:

```
awk -v RS= '{sub(/SET ENG.*SET ENG[^\n]*\n/, "")} 1' file
start text
end text
blah blah
blah blah
```

This example is using same sample data as in Jotne's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your new desired output, I would interpret what you're trying to do as this:

- If `/SET ENG/` matches, switch off output
- If `/SET [anything else]/` switch it back on
- Print all `SET` lines

This script does that:

```
$ awk '/SET/ { if (/ENG/) { print; f = 0 } else f = 1 } f' file
SET ENG_1
SET ENG_2
SET TEST
blah blah
blah blah
SET ENG_5
SET OPEN
blah blah
blah blah
SET ENG_10
```

Comment: See my updated question above that should make things clearer. thank you.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on my interpretation of your requirements. I suggest you edit your question to provide us with some simple rules, as I have done in my answer.

Comment: Your answer works, but it doesn't write to the file like sed does. Does awk have an inplace editing option?

Comment: Some versions of awk do, although the simplest solution is just to use a temporary file: `awk '...' file > tmp && mv tmp file`. Any "in-place" option is going to create a temporary file anyway. As I mentioned before, I would strongly suggest editing your question to clarify it.

Comment: Tom, I edited again but i'm not sure how to clarify it better. Would it be better for me to delete the post and try asking this on a unix forum? I am getting some downvotes and did not intend to annoy anyone.

Comment: @user3101337 Downvotes aren't anything personal, they mean that your question is unclear. Deleting questions should only be seen as a last resort. I think it is clearer now, so you should keep it here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks from your question like this is all you need:

```
$ grep 'SET ENG_' file
SET ENG_1
SET ENG_2
```

If that's not what you wanted, edit your question to clarify your requirements, provide more truly representative input and the precise expected output given that input.

Comment: See my updated question above that should make things clearer. thank you.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't. You say `I only want to remove text between lines that start with SET ENG_#` but then your example shows you removing the lines between `SET ENG_2` and `SET TEST`.

Comment: Now it says `I want to remove all lines between SET ENG_ and the next line that starts with SET but does not contain ENG` but the example shows you removing lines between `SET ENG_1` and `SET ENG_2`. I'm sure whatever it is you are trying to do has an absolutely trivial and clear awk solution but so far idk what you actually want...

Comment: Tom added that last part. I'll remove it. I already have a solution from potong above.

Comment: So long as you fully understand it and will be able to easily modify it for your next similar but slightly different problem or when your requirements change slightly then you should definitely go with a sed solution. If, on the other hand, you find the sed solution a little less clear than you'd like then you might want to persevere to get an awk solution.

Comment: I've never used awk, I'll have to look into it, especially if it's easier to follow than sed.

Comment: If you are using more than `s`, `g`, and `p` (with `-n`) in sed then you are using the wrong tool. All of the other bizarre, arcane sed incantations to do things like handle multi-line input records became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented and are only used today for the mental exercise, like trying to solve a complex puzzle. Get the book `Effective Awk Programming`, Fourth Edition, by Arnold Robbins to see how clear, simple, robust, and efficient manipulating text can and should be.